# How to make c#.net label blink when text changes

Tags: c#, label

I'm making a basic student management system using visual studio. When I update a student's information, I have a blank label that changes to "[student's] information has been changed." I want this label to blink for a couple seconds to get the user's attention. The label is called lblStuTitle.

Comment: please add WinForms or WPF (or whatever) to your tags

Comment: Blinking UI elements went out with the 1980s.  To rollback time and annoy your user, use a timer.

Answer (score 0):

I think a timer will do the trick.

```
    bool Blink = false;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblStuTitle.Visible = Blink;
        Blink = !Blink;
    }
```

And when you're done you can make sure it's visible by

```
lblStuTitle.Visible = true;
timer1.Stop();
```